# Why the direction of text is not getting changed ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, webforms

I am trying to change the orientation(direction of text) of textbox upon selectedIndexChanged event of drop down but not working.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="English" Value="Eng"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Persian" Value="fa"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeTextDirection()
        {
            document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.textAlign="right";
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

Event:

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ChangeTextDirection();");
        }
```

I am trying to change it from 'left to right' to 'right to left'

Comment: Set the style "direction:RTL;" for right to left.

Comment: But style element exists on client side but I have to change it from server side i.e. selectedIndexChanged event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change it in your event handler as well using the [Controls Style Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx47a5t2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); something like below

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.TextBox1.Style["textAlign"] = "right";
    }
```